# How can I work with three different foreign keys in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to make an create and edit page for accounts [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAJe3.png) (customers) just like I did [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2fzO.png) for Cities and Countries.

The only difference between the two is that account have multiple foreigns keys on the backend code. The backend code is working on the read account page over [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hedRi.png), but once I try to edit the page I see [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeNJ4.png). The one account which is in there I've added it in SQL itself.

Code for create or edit city is as follows

```
@page "/city"
@page "/city/{id:int}"
@inject ICityService CityService

<h3>City</h3>

@if (Id == null)
{
    <PageTitle>Create a new City</PageTitle>
    <h3>Create a new City</h3>
}
else
{
    <PageTitle>Edit @city.CityName</PageTitle>
    <h3>Edit @city.CityName</h3>
}

<EditForm Model="city" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit">
    <div>
        <label for="CityName">City Name</label>
        <InputText id="cityname" @bind-Value="city.CityName" class="form-control"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="cityabbrevation">City Abbrevation</label>
        <InputText id="Cityabbrevation" @bind-Value="city.CityAbbrevation" class="form-control"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>country</label><br />
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="city.CountryId" class="form-select">
            @foreach (var country in CityService.Countries)
            {
                <option value="@country.Id">@country.CountryName</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@btnText</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="DeleteCity">Delete City</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    string btnText = string.Empty;

    CityMain city = new CityMain { Country = new CountryMain() };

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        btnText = Id == null ? "Save New City" : "Update City";
        await CityService.GetCountries();
    }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (Id == null)
        {
            city.Country = CityService.Countries[0];
            city.CountryId = city.Country.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            city = await CityService.GetSingleCity((int)Id);
        }
    }

    async Task HandleSubmit()
    {
        if (Id == null)
        {
            await CityService.CreateCity(city);
        }
        else
        {
            await CityService.UpdateCity(city);
        }
    }

    async Task DeleteCity()
    {
        await CityService.DeleteCity(city.Id);
    }
}
```

Code for create or edit account is as follows:

```
@page "/account"
@page "/account/{id:int}"
@inject IAccountService AccountService

<h3>Account</h3>

@if (Id == null)
{
    <PageTitle>Create a new Account</PageTitle>
    <h3>Create a new Account</h3>
}
else
{
    <PageTitle>Edit @account.AccountName</PageTitle>
    <h3>Edit @account.AccountName</h3>
}

<EditForm Model="account" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit">
    <div>
        <label>AccountType</label><br/>
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="account.AccountTypeId" class="form-select">
            @foreach (var accountType in AccountService.AccountTypes)
            {
                <option value="@accountType.Id">@accountType.AccountTypeName</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <label for="AccountName">Account Name</label>
        <InputText id="AccountName" @bind-Value="account.AccountName" class="form-control"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="StreetName">Street Name</label>
        <InputText id="StreetName" @bind-Value="account.StreetName" class="form-control"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="StreetNumber">Street Number</label>
        <InputText id="StreetNumber" @bind-Value="account.StreetNumber" class="form-control"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="ZipCode">Zip Code</label>
        <InputText id="ZipCode" @bind-Value="account.ZipCode" class="form-control"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>city</label><br/>
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="account.CityId" class="form-select">
            @foreach (var city in AccountService.Cities)
            {
                <option value="@city.Id">@city.CityName</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <label>tariffgroup</label><br/>
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="account.TariffGroupId" class="form-select">
            @foreach (var tariffGroup in AccountService.TariffGroups)
            {
                <option value="@tariffGroup.Id">@tariffGroup.TariffGroupName</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@btnText</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="DeleteAccount">Delete Account</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    string btnText = string.Empty;

    AccountMain account = new AccountMain
        {
            AccountType = new AccountTypeMain(),
            TariffGroup = new TariffGroupMain(),
            City = new CityMain()
        };

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        btnText = Id == null ? "Save New Account" : "Update Account";
        await AccountService.GetAccounts();
    }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (Id == null)
        {
            account.AccountType = AccountService.AccountTypes[0];
            account.AccountTypeId = account.AccountType.Id;
            account.TariffGroup = AccountService.TariffGroups[0];
            account.TariffGroupId = account.TariffGroup.Id;
            account.City = AccountService.Cities[0];
            account.CityId = account.City.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            account = await AccountService.GetSingleAccount((int)Id);
        }
    }

    async Task HandleSubmit()
    {
        if (Id == null)
        {
            await AccountService.CreateAccount(account);
        }
        else
        {
            await AccountService.UpdateAccount(account);
        }
    }

    async Task DeleteAccount()
    {
        await AccountService.DeleteAccount(account.Id);
    }
}
```

```
I think the problem is somewhere in the @code section, but I don't know exactly where and how to solve it.
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong or have any advise ?

If any more information is needed, please let me know.

thank you in advance